# Display binary PDF in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, binary, base64

Is there a way in react to take a binary of a pdf document and display the pdf? I've looked at [react-pdf](https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf) but it doesn't seem to support binary. I also looked at using an iframe, but again, there I can only use base64... If there's a way to convert the binary into base64 I still might be able to display it in the iframe but I'm at a bit of a loss here.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa

Answer (score 0):

I will share my working example. I am displaying using base64 here so you have to convert your binary to base64 yourself.

```
getDoc = binary => e => {
    if (binary != null) {
      var contentType = "application/pdf";

      this.setState({
        doc: "data:" + contentType + ";base64," + binary
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        doc: ""
      });
    }
  };
```

A button for showing modal

```
render() {
<button
            className="btn btn-warning btn-sm"
            href="#"
            role="button"
            data-toggle="modal"
            data-target="#previewModal"
            onClick={this.getDoc(your_file)}
>
```

Display file using embed

```
<div
        id="previewModal"
        className="modal fade"
        role="dialog"
      >
        <div className="modal-dialog modal-lg">
          {/* <!-- Modal content--> */}
          <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="modal-header">
              <h4 className="modal-title">Doc</h4>
              <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                &times;
              </button>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-body">
              <embed
                src={this.state.doc}
                id="displayFile"
                alt="your image"
                width="100%"
                height="99%"
                style={{ borderStyle: "solid" }}
                type="application/pdf"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
}
```